# Remote Connection to SQL-Server for data extract

Tags: sql-server

I have zero experience with MSSQL Server, but I'm trying to determine the most effective way to extract data from table into flat files from a remote location.
Here's the usage case scenario:

We are a data-integration company and we have some customers who run software ( ERP ) on top of a MS SQL Server. The ERP vendor previously supported a extract and delivery process directly to our ( company ) location. The ERP company has now become unresponsive to our ongoing extract issues ( bugs ) and we're preparing for the possibility of losing customers as a result (even though we have a contract with the software company).

I'm assuming that there's a way for us to connect directly to the MSSQL server and extract the data, bypassing the ERP vendor extract solution altogether, but I'm not familiar w/ MSSQL or Connections / Connectors at all.

Would anyone be willing to share with me if this sort of thing is possible and what the best route for me to continue my research might be?

Comment: Use SSIS or SQL Server Import and Export Wizard.

Comment: Is the database server on site or based at a third party location? What's your access to that server? Do you imagine you're going to have the rights / credentials to access the data?

Comment: Best route? Hire a consultant for an hour or two instead of wasting days. I'm available :D

Comment: If you are a *data-integration* company, don't you have staff who could take care of this?

Comment: @Molenpad The customers' database server is on site, and their location.  We have zero access to that server currently, but we imagine that we'll be able to have the rights / credentials to access the data, yes.

Comment: @FutbolFan I was thinking SSIS was going to be the way to go from the limited research.  We don't currently have SQL Server ( our customer's do ), would we have to purchase SQL Server to get SSIS and then do all the ETL'ing from that one instances ( We have multiple customers locations, btw, that would need this )?

Comment: @agenovese how can I connect w/ you?  I certainly don't want to waste days on this...  :)

Comment: As several here have mentioned SSIS is probably your best bet. The export wizard in SSMS can create a dtsx package which can be saved and reused. You should be able to do this with the free versions of software. However your customers should already have licenses for this. If you want all of the features of integration services onsite at your work you would need at least SQL Server standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FutbolFan said, best approach is to use SSIS (which takes a bit more time) or SQL Server Import/Export Wizard (the feasible option, in your case).

1. Right Click on the Database in question ans Select Tasks -> Export Data (the wizard will open up)
2. Select The Database in question as your source (might have to switch between SQL 10.0 or 11.0 depending on your version.
3. Select Flat File as your destination.  You'll be able to customize your delimiters and text qualifiers here
4. Select the Object you want to export.  You can do this by using the Object selector, or by using a custom query.  Up to you.
5. Run the package for each table you want to export, verify your results.

Comment: We don't have SQL Server (We run Postgres as a data-warehouse).  We need to connect to customers that do have SQL Server, to issue queries so we can extract the data ( via a scripting language or other unknown solution ).

Comment: As mguerraTorres and FutbolFan have stated, SSIS would probably be your best option for this. You can quickly create a package, configure a connection to the SQL Server, and then export the data into a flat file. This would also be re-usable for multiple customers, not a one time thing like using the Import/Export wizard.

Comment: @mjpeters: Your only tag in your question is SQL-Server, so I answered appropriately.  My advice is to have your customers set up a new user with data_reader access (or just READ access on the particular objects you're extracting data from) and connect to their servers via SQL Server Management studio remotely.  I also agree with Jason B.'s answer.